# VBA using cells inside range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have the following VBA code:

```
Sheets("results").Range("C2:M6").Value = arr
```

Where `arr` is a 5,11 dimension array.
The above formula works and paste the value of `arr` in the specified Excel range.
But when I try to use:

```
Sheets("results").Range(Cells(2,6),Cells(6,13)).Value = arr
```

The formula does not work and gives me a runtime error 1004.

My question is how to solve this problem.

The bigger issue that I am trying to solve is pasting the 5,11 dimension arrays one below the other in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to qualify **Cells** :

```
With Sheets("results")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(6, 13)).Value = arr
End With
```